# Angular5 httpClient get:Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I am trying to get a list of Users from an API but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:2482)
at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1796)
at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:2547)
at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (http.js:1466)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
```

I have a login component that calls the homeService.getUsers() which uses HttpClient to retrieve the users but the http request never reaches the server.

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeService } from '../service/home.service';
import { User } from '../domain/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = {
      id: undefined,
      userName: undefined,
      password: undefined
  }; 
  users: User[];

  constructor(
    private homeService: HomeService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.homeService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }
}
```

Home.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../domain/user';
import { MessageService } from '../service/message.service';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  private usersUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/users';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }

  getUsers (): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(users => this.log(`fetched users`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getUsers', []))
      );
  }

  /**
  * Handle Http operation that failed.
  * Let the app continue.
  * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
  * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
  */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(message);
  }

}
```

and the app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HomeService } from './service/home.service';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { MessageService } from './service/message.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MessagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
      headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
    })
  ],
  providers: [HomeService, MessageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can see the error message displayed in the logging, so it seems like an error from the HttpClient. But I can't figure out why it is failing before sending the Http request to the server.

Comment: Bot  cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie' and headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header' are undefined, thats why!

Comment: But if I remove the options of the import and leave the import as 'HttpClientXsrfModule' I keep getting the error

Comment: Issue solved, usersUrl was badly assigned. Modified it to: private usersUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/users';

Comment: fwiw: I had this error and the fix was to wrap the url variable with tick marks in my service as such \`${url}\`

Answer (score 20):

I got the same issue. The problem was that I had declared the url, but when doing the  httpget, i realized that the url was not assigned with any value:

Probable case:
Example:
private yourUrl: string;

and in your http call:
return this.http.get(this.yourUrl, {headers : this.headers})

Answer (score 16):

it seems you have declared a variable wrongly thus making it undefined:
Try this

For neat coding

```
interface User = {
      id: number;
      userName: string;
      password: string;
  }

user: User;
```

Also correct this line from

```
private usersUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/users';
```

To

```
private usersUrl =  'http://localhost:8080/users';
```

This is likely where the problem is

Comment: Thank you! Instead of my `=` I had a `:` cannot believe it.

Comment: Same in my case. Thank you, it saved my day

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the URL that you have passed:
`private usersUrl: http://localhost:8080/users';` .

It should be like:
`private usersUrl: string='http://localhost:8080/users';`

Comment: Thanks this was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

i think your url declaration is not  correct 
try the following way:

`private usersUrl =  'http://localhost:8080/users';`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
As @Canlla said, it was necessary to change the visibility of the url variable from public to private.

> Strange, but something was changing its value! Anyway, it must be
>   private, since we don't need acess it on tamplate.

In my case, in addition, I needed to add NgIf / NgElse to avoid data binding before the load completes:

```html
<mat-list *ngIf="transactions | async; let transactions;else loading">
      <div *ngFor="let transaction of transactions">
        <h3 mat-subheader>{{ transaction.dueDate }}</h3>        
        <mat-list-item>
          <img matListAvatar src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="...">
          <span matLine class="mat-body-2"> {{transaction.description}} </span>
          <p matLine class="col col-6 left-align">
            <span class="mat-body-1"> {{transaction.categoryName}} </span>
            <br>
            <span class="mat-caption"> {{transaction.accountName}} </span>
          </p>
          <p class="col col-6 right-align">
            <span class="mat-subheading">{{ transaction.amount | currency:'BRL':'symbol' }}</span>
          </p>
        </mat-list-item>       
      </div>
    </mat-list>

<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

So here:
`<mat-list *ngIf="transactions | async; let transactions;else loading">`

I have *ngIf with `async` pipe to show `mat-list` if `transactions` has loaded.
Next `let user` statement if true creating a local template variable that Angular assigns the value from the Observable.

Otherwise `else loading` tells Angular if the condition is not met to show the loading template.

Check it out this excelent post from @coryrylan: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar kind of error, and, in order to solve it, I looked  up a bit and realised I declared the URL in wrongly.

The declaration should be something like this

```
private urlVariable = 'http://sampleurl.com';
```